# VHDL behavioural D Flip-Flop with R & S

Tags: vhdl

Hi can any of you with more experience with VHDL Quartus II please set me right on this please.
I have the following Entity and behavioural Architecture for a D Flip-Flop with Set and Reset.

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;

ENTITY Q1 IS
PORT (D,R,S,CLK :   IN      std_logic;
        Q               :   OUT std_logic
        );
END ENTITY Q1;

ARCHITECTURE behavioural OF Q1 IS
BEGIN
D_FF    :   PROCESS (CLK,R,S)
BEGIN
    IF          R = '0' THEN Q <= '0';
    ELSIF       S = '0' THEN Q <=   '1';
    ELSIF   (rising_edge(CLK)) THEN Q <= D;
    END IF;
END PROCESS D_FF;
END ARCHITECTURE behavioural;
```

When I compile the code using Quartus II I get the following error message :

Warning (335093): TimeQuest Timing Analyzer is analyzing 1 combinational loops as latches.

I think it is a warning for the incomplete output assignments of the R & S inputs, but when I make a D Flip-Flop latch with only the SET input this error message does not appear when compiled. This leaves me thinking maybe I made an error when writing the architecture? If anyone has any answers or useful info that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have described a clock-edge triggered flip-flop (FF) with both an asynchronous reset and an asynchronous set. Only one of them is supported at the same time because AFAIK, all FFs on Altera FPGAs have only an asynchronous reset.

An asynchronous set is emulated on Altera FPGAs by inverting the FF data input and output and then resetting it to low instead of setting it to high. It looks like this:

[image: asynchronous set on Altera FPGAs]

Don't overlook the inverter on the `D` input of the FF. If `S` is low, then the FF **itself** is asynchronously reset, but due the negation of the `Q` output afterwars, it behaves as an asynchronous set of output `Q` of your entity `Q1`. If `S` is high, the FF stores the negated input at the rising clock-edge, which is again negated at the output. As you see, the asynchronous reset port of the *FF* is already used, and thus, cannot be used for an additional asynchronous reset of your entity `Q1`.

I recommend to use flip-flops with synchronous set and reset instead:

```
ARCHITECTURE sync_rs OF Q1 IS
BEGIN
D_FF    :   PROCESS (CLK)
BEGIN
    IF (rising_edge(CLK)) THEN
        IF          R = '0' THEN Q <= '0';
        ELSIF       S = '0' THEN Q <= '1';
        ELSE                     Q <= D;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END PROCESS D_FF;
END ARCHITECTURE sync_rs;
```

Comment: Again Many thanks Martin. From your original answer I thought you were saying there is a way to emulate both asynchronous Set and Reset inputs at the same time on the Altera FPGA's

Answer (score 2):

Flip flops in FPGA devices usually have either asynchronous set or reset, but not both, so Altera Quartus tries to make the requested circuit with latches instead of dedicated hardware.

However, for most cases that is not what you want, so instead use flip flops with either asynchronous reset or set, or use synchronous set and and reset as Martin Zabel suggested in his answer.

Note that asynchronous reset have an advantage over synchronous reset in high speed designs, since the asynchronous reset does not add any login in the main synchronous data path, which is usually the critical path for high-speed designs.

Finally, for asynchronous reset, it is a good habit to use two `if` separate statements, with reset last, so clocking is not dependent on assertion of reset.  It is not an issue for a single bit flip flop, but if more signals are controlled in the same process, and reset does not apply to all signals, then clocking should not be dependent on reset for those signal without reset, since that will infer latches.  Code like:

```
D_FF : PROCESS (CLK, R)
BEGIN
  IF rising_edge(CLK) THEN
    Q <= D;
  END IF;
  IF R = '0' THEN
    Q <= '0';
  END IF;
END PROCESS D_FF;
```

Comment: Hi Morten, Thanks for the good information. I will try the code you posted will the reset not occur late though with it running sequentially after the CLK IF statement?

Comment: All assigns in the process will occur at the time the process executes, so if both clocked and reset assign takes place, the assign by reset will just override the assign by clock, which is the purpose.

Comment: OK I was under the impression that the Process assignment would implement all statements sequentially .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, I made the R & S inputs asynchronous on purpose. I have been working through a VHDL text book "Free Range VHDL" and have come across the following question in the Exercises:
[image]

The question asks for both inputs to be asynchronous. You say this can be emulated with Altera by inverting the input and output and resetting it to low instead of high. Can you expand on this a little? Thanks

Comment: Your original question contains a perfectly reasonable answer to this problem. The fact that a particular vendor's tools do not support the functionality exactly as intended, I don't see as being really that relevant. I would take away from this that yes, you do know how to answer the question, but also, (and importantly) that not everything you can write in VHDL can be neatly mapped into a real FPGA device.

Comment: I have added an explanation of asynchronous set of flip-flops on Altera FPGAs in my answer.